# Why C# lock shouldn't be used for long operations?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking

A lot of articles say: don't use lock to synchronise long operations and I follow this rule. But I'm curious what is actually so wrong about it? Is this about some precious resource consuming?

Also, will it help if I use AutoResetEvent instead? Or I should rather forget about locking long operations and go for asynchronous programming?

Comment: Please post some code what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I guess the post is meant to be a more general question.

Answer (score 17):

First off, if you don't understand the reason for the rule then you're cargo cult programming. It is *vital* that you understand the reasons for these rules, rather than applying them blindly.

So, two reasons to hold locks for a short amount of time:

(1) long locks equal poor performance. Suppose you have a resource that only one person can use at a time. Do you really want your housemate to be doing his taxes and binge watching netflix in the shower? No, you want them to get in and get out so someone else can use it.

(2) long locks equal deadlocks. If you're in a lock for a long time, odds are good you're calling a lot of code. Which increases the odds that the code you're calling has a lock order inversion that you don't know about.

So, the standard advice is: lock for as little time as possible, and have many fine-grained locks rather than single course grained locks.

Of course, the standard advice *also* is that having many fine-grained locks *also* increases opportunities for deadlocks because now you have more locks that could be inverted. And having many fine-grained locks also increases the likelihood that there is an unknown race where something runs between two locked regions that you haven't considered.  So the standard advice is: have a small number of coarse-grained locks that lock for large sections of code.

The standard advice is contradictory. Why is that? Because *managing shared memory in multithreaded programs via monitor locking is fundamentally a bad idea*. It's the standard practice, but that doesn't make it good.

> Also, will it help if I use AutoResetEvent instead? Or I should rather forget about locking long operations and go for asynchronous programming?

My advice is to use the highest-level operation you can. If you can get away with no asynchrony, do it. If not, consider process level parallelism or single threaded asynchrony, depending on whether you are processor bound or IO latency bound. If those don't work for whatever reason then treat threads as lightweight processes with *no* shared memory; use the TPL to manage your threads for you.

And so on.  Dealing with locks or interlocked operations or volatiles should be a last resort, and these tools should be used as primitives to build higher-level tools.

Comment: The essence is use high level abstractions, TPL, Concurrent Collections, try not to use the low level constructs like `lock`, `EventWaitHandle` anymore. Abstractions does a far better job in managing the resources.

Comment: What if performance or deadlocks isn't an issue? Maybe you only want the locks to serialize multiple tasks. Is it still bad? Lets say I have N tasks triggered by timers. They are not time critical but it is important they don't run at the same time. Will I run into resource or other problems if I just surround each task with a global lock? Does it matter if the tasks take 1 second, 10 seconds, 10 minutes? (I know there are other ways to solve it)

Comment: @adrianm: Your question is: if we say "in our scenario there are no problems" then are there problems? No, if you don't care about performance or correctness, then by definition you don't have performance or correctness problems.

Comment: @adrianm: But I would ask in your scenario how you expect to deal with single threaded re-entrancy. Locks don't protect against that.

Comment: @adrianm: I would also note that solving the problem of tasks triggered by timers that must not run concurrently does not solve the problem of ensuring that they run in the same order that the timers fired. When two threads are both waiting on a lock there is no guarantee which one gets to go next. The operating system is not obliged to be fair.

Comment: Why do you think I don't care about correctness or believe a lock solves reentrancy and ordering problems? The OP asked why locks must be short and all replies says it is for performance. My question is just why I can't (shouldn't)  protect a slow shared resource with locks. If 95% of the time is spent in the shared resource, performance of my code is a non-issue.

Comment: And a concrete example. I have an order processing unit which for licensing reasons only accept one batch at a time. During the night, N customers prepare batches which arrives irregulary from various sources via polling tasks (ftp, webservices, local files etc) . Processing of the batches can take 10 seconds or an hour depening on size. Order doesn't matter since they are all processed during the night anyway. My solution is a queue and a worker thread but why wouldn't a lock work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141658/discussion-between-eric-lippert-and-adrianm).

Answer (score 1):

Simple idea behind it. `Lock` essentially blocks other threads from entering critical section. Say critical section already has one `thread` which is doing some work then another thread is waiting to access the critical section. This makes these `threads` in a matter execute synchroniously. That raises the question why wont you just use single thread for that?

So first reason is that you might as well run single thread for it.

Another point, by making critical section long operations you also block all other threads waiting for lock to be lifted thus potentially increasing executing time of code by `thread` amount.

Second reason, your code will be extremely slow in a highly concurrent environment.

Comment: '... you might as well run a single thread for it' is not universal. A lock on a specific node in a large tree with multiple concurrent updaters should have a low collision rate but sequentialize if two editors try to update the same node at the same time. A 'lock' at this point seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

C# lock statements are used to restrict access of a critical section from multiple threads. This statement ensures a mutually exclusive access for a single thread execution, until the release of the lock. For example, if a file write condition is set to have block all access while write operation is in-progress, wrapping lock statement around the file write code makes sure to satisfy the condition.

Now, if the execution time becomes prolonged, the other threads queue up at the lock. That results to sluggish response time, degraded performance or sometime leads to call failure due to timeouts. Example -

```
private Object lockObj = new Object();  

 public void FileOperation(decimal amount)  
 {  
    //Subsequent thread calls will queue up 
    lock (lockObj)  
    {          
      using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt", true))
            {
                //Long running operation  
                for(var i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
                {
                   file.WriteLine("Fourth line");
                }
            } 
    }
}
```

[Original Post](https://www.apnastudy.com/publicforumdetails/AVuH5Pwu84he5u4soIOK/what-is-usage-of-lock-statement-in-c-and-when-to-avoid-it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another important thing about long locks -> priority inversion (see this [link](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/what-is-priority-inversion-and-how-do-yo/230600008)). Let's consider the following.

A low prio thread locks a resource for a long time. A high prio thread needs also access to this resource. Worst case: the low prio thread holds the lock, a high prio thread is started and accesses the lock. In this case the low prio thread is scheduled to "inactive" and the high prio thread to "active". Problem: the high prio thread is blocked because the low prio thread still holds the lock.

I know this problem is obvious when you read about it, but in complex code things aren't always that clear ... Reducing lock scope can help to avoid such situations.

If possible switch to async, but also be aware that there are also possible deadlock scenarios(see this [post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) for example).